# How do I create an html embeddable widget using Clojure / ClojureScript?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I want to create a Web Widget. It must access remote clojure data structure and display elements of it requested by a widget parameter. The visual style would also be dictated remotely.

EDIT:

Youtube has this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Z6bFyVGvg28" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Google Maps has this:

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.ca/maps?q=yahoo+corp&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=&amp;ll=37.417223,-122.025112&amp;spn=0.006295,0.006295&amp;t=h&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.ca/maps?q=yahoo+corp&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=&amp;ll=37.417223,-122.025112&amp;spn=0.006295,0.006295&amp;t=h&amp;iwloc=A&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">Agrandir le plan</a></small>
```

So I suspect an iframe that targets a specific URL handle by the remote server could do the job.

There are indeed tradeoffs between writing your widget inside an iframe or simply inline the page and make it part of the dom of the hosting page.
http://prettyprint.me/prettyprint.me/2009/05/30/widgets-iframe-vs-inline/

Comment: This is too broad and abstract...

Comment: @user1184248, could you be more specific? Perhaps give a practical example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very similar request which it's achieved in this David Nolen demostration project:

https://github.com/swannodette/om-sync

based on his clojurescript react.js thin layer called"om":

https://github.com/swannodette/om

Comment: Would it be possible to elaborate a bit (I am a beginner). Thank you!

Comment: @user1184248 I think that you'll need to follow the react tutorial (focused on creating an embeddable widget) http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html and then om tutorial https://github.com/swannodette/om/wiki/Basic-Tutorial :)

Comment: @user1184248 don't forget Timothy Baldridge - Core.Async  Video! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=enwIIGzhahw